# 3.5.x Theme Customize: Handling Custom Control Requests

Tags: images, uploads, javascript, theme-customizer

I am extending the WP_Customize_Image_Control as a means to include an upload-able word mark for a site. The control works just fine, but I need to do some post process handling on the image (i.e. check image dimensions, file type, etc...). In other words I need to validate the upload. Is there an event listener in the javascript of the API, that I can override, in order to do this?

Comment: Your going to want to do your validation in php that way you can save / delete / modify the image based on the results. Do some google searching, i know you can get file extensions and file sizes using php, i believe you can also get dimensions. Look into mime types for determining the file type.

Comment: Thanks, but I have the PHP processing part down, I am looking for a event listener in the javascript that will prevent the upload from occurring. I may not have worded my question correctly, but I need to catch the upload process, and tell the user that the uploaded image is not valid.